# While TypeORM Seeding I am facing following error. Any pointer what i am missing? Error "QueryFailedError: relation "zipcode" does not exist"

Tags: node.js, migration, typeorm, seeding

TypeORM:
Requirement: We need to seed data into Table.

If i run migration or data seeding (within migrations) separately it works fine. However i need to accomplish this task in a single go.

I have created a migration to create table and insert data in table at the same time. When i run the migration, it returns an error: Error during migration run:
QueryFailedError: relation "zipcode" does not exist
while i didn't define any relation in migration.

my Migration code is following

````
    public async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        await queryRunner.query(
            `CREATE TABLE "zipcode" (
                "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
                "zipCode" character varying NOT NULL,
                "city" character varying NOT NULL,
                "state" character varying NOT NULL,
                "county" character varying,
                "country" character varying,
                PRIMARY KEY ("id"))`
        );

        await getConnection()
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .insert()
            .into("zipcode")
            .values([
                {
                id: 1,
                zipCode: "501",```
             …

**Part of error**

```query: CREATE TABLE "zipcode" (
                "id" SERIAL NOT NULL,
                "zipCode" character varying NOT NULL,
                "city" character varying NOT NULL,
                "state" character varying NOT NULL,
                "county" character varying,
                "country" character varying,
                PRIMARY KEY ("id"))
query: INSERT INTO "zipcode"("zipCode", "city", "state", "county", "country") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id" -- PARAMETERS: ["501","Holtsville","New York","Suffolk County","US"]
query failed: INSERT INTO "zipcode"("zipCode", "city", "state", "county", "country") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id" -- PARAMETERS: ["501","Holtsville","New York","Suffolk County","US"]
error: error: relation "zipcode" does not exist```
````

Answer (score 0):

In a migration you must use the provided `queryRunner` to execute queries.

**DO NOT USE `createConnection`, `getConnection`, etc...**

See [this answer](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2087#issuecomment-389817679) from *pleerock* (creator of TypeORM).

Working example:

```js
import {MigrationInterface, QueryRunner} from "typeorm";

export class ZipCodeMigration implements MigrationInterface {

    async up(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        // Create 'zipcode' table
        await queryRunner.createTable(new Table({
            name: "zipcode",
            columns: [
                {
                     name: "id",
                     type: "serial",
                     isPrimary: true
                },
                {
                     name: "zipCode",
                     type: "character varying"
                },
                {
                     name: "city",
                     type: "character varying"
                },
                {
                     name: "state",
                     type: "character varying"
                },
                {
                     name: "county",
                     type: "character varying",
                     isNullable: true
                },
                {
                     name: "country",
                     type: "character varying",
                     isNullable: true
                },
            ]
        }));

        // Populate 'zipcode' table
        await queryRunner
            .manager
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .insert()
            .into("zipcode")
            .values({ ... })
            .execute();      
    }

    async down(queryRunner: QueryRunner): Promise<void> {
        // Drop 'zipcode' table
        await queryRunner.dropTable("zipcode");
    }
}
```

Docs/Sources:

1. [`createTable`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a0f09de8400ac7c94df33f8213ef0eec79b9239d/src/query-runner/QueryRunner.ts#L213) function
2. [`Table`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a0f09de8400ac7c94df33f8213ef0eec79b9239d/src/schema-builder/table/Table.ts#L15) class
3. [`TableColumn`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/a0f09de8400ac7c94df33f8213ef0eec79b9239d/src/schema-builder/table/TableColumn.ts#L6) class